# Can I replace the latest version mail.jar in Axis2 default download?

Tags: java, jar, version, jakarta-mail, apache-axis

We are using in our library axis2 library. Axis2 latest version comes with mail.jar version 1.4. We need newer version of mail.jar in the classpath, so can I just replace latest version of mail.jar to Axis2 default download libs?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out the Axis2 src and recompiled by changing to version 1.5.0 of JavaMail and it compiles and tests run successfully.

[image: axis javamail module test success]

Note also reading through the changelog as far as I can tell the changes described are additive.
https://javamail.java.net/docs/JavaMail-1.5-changes.txt

It looks like you can replace the jar but you should test it to be sure. It should really only matter if you are using the MailTransportSender in Axis2.

Btw you might want to consider switching away from Axis and use CXF as in my experience and in various benchmarks like http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws14/ CXF is a lot faster.